# How to install apk from sd

Tags: android-pc

Hi all I need to install Asphalt 8 Airborne, that occupy 1.56gb of space. But I get an error while I'm downloading it from the playstore. So, I was trying to download it from the pc. But if I put the file on a microSD, will it install the file on the sd or on the internal memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you have it on your sd card, the stock android doesn't allow you to move the whole application to the card. Of you have a custom rom, then it can be installed to the sd card, or of you have space in your internal memory, then first install it to it and then use move to sd card in app manager, to move it's app data files to it.